# Comparison between string and serial port input is always false

Tags: c#, visual-studio, arduino

I am making a game where I get dice input from the serial port (Arduino). Since the input isn't just simply a number but is "e" + the number I am trying to get the number in Visual Studio.

This, however, doesn't go as simply as you'd expect. I am using simple if statements, see my code:

```
string RolledNumberCode = Program.form1.DicePort.ReadExisting();
 if (RolledNumberCode.Contains("e"))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(RolledNumberCode);
                    int RolledNumber = 0;
                    if (RolledNumberCode.Contains("1")) { RolledNumber = 1; }
                    else if (RolledNumberCode.Contains("2")) { RolledNumber = 2; }
                    else if (RolledNumberCode.Contains("3")) { RolledNumber = 3; }
                    else if (RolledNumberCode.Contains("4")) { RolledNumber = 4; }
                    else if (RolledNumberCode.Contains("5")) { RolledNumber = 5; }
                    else if (RolledNumberCode.Contains("6")) { RolledNumber = 6; }

                    dice.RollAnalog(RolledNumber);
```

After this didn't seem to work I tested it with messageboxes and the c# does read the RolledNumberCode correctly, for example a messagebox pops up showing e4. But then I put the RolledNumber in a MessageBox, it is always 0.

Does somebody know what I am doing wrong here? I strongly think there is just a simple error in my code but I can't find it :(

Comment: Have you debugged it...? Learn how to use the debugger.

Comment: Have you by any chance got a property somewhere called `RolledNumber` that you meant to set, rather than the local `RolledNumber` that you are setting?

Comment: Try : RolledNumberCode.Text.Contains("2").  You have a text box and need to get the text.

Comment: Just before the `dice.RollAnalog(...)`, try putting a statement like `MessageBox.Show("Have set RolledNumber to '" + RolledNumber + "'");`. This checks that the code is executing the path expected.

Comment: @jdweng, `RolledNumberCode` is of type `string`, check first line of code

Comment: Have you debugged code line by line, what value comes in `RolledNumberCode`? if it is `e4`, your code will definitely go inside if condtion

Comment: @ArdrianHHH , I tried that and it does show the correct number in that messagebox. However, the messagebox that should show the number at its own still shows 0.

Comment: @Pim_vh, Have you tried solution which I suggest in answer. Is it helpful?

Comment: @MatthewWatson , thanks for bringing that up, that was indeed the case haha. I'm a beginning programmer so there's much to learn in code quality :)

Comment: What is the code that shows the wrong value and the lines between it and the code in the question? The code in the question works, so the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: I tried the code you provided.In the final code, if I used  MessageBox.Show(RolledNumber.ToString());, it will pop up '4'. However, you used dice.RollAnalog(RolledNumber);, I want to know what the method is used for.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `if else` ladder I would suggest, remove `e` from string i.e `"e1"` to `"1"` and assign it to `RolledNumber`

```
string RolledNumberCode = Program.form1.DicePort.ReadExisting();
if (RolledNumberCode.Contains("e"))
{
    int RolledNumber = Convert.ToInt32(RolledNumberCode.Replace("e",""));
    dice.RollAnalog(RolledNumber);
}
```

Comment: This was not a reason that caused the error but this method massively improves my code quality anyway. Thanks :)

Comment: I am glad that it helped in some other way ;)